# Compute the minimal polynomial of a companion matrix without using Cayley-Hamilton

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, companion-matrices

I have $$A = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & \cdots & 0& -a_{0} \\  1 & \cdots & 0 & -a_{1}\\ \vdots &\ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0 &\cdots & 1 & -a_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} \in M_{n}$$ and, as the title says, I want to know the minimal polynomial, but without using Cayley-Hamilton (as I'm trying to do an alternative, inductive proof of the theorem).

I know that $$m_{e_1} = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$$

Maybe I can compute $m_{e_i}$ for the other canonical vectors, but it's ugly, and I'm searching for a faster, non-horrible way. Could someone help me?

Comment: OK, I got it now. As $e_1$ is cyclic, and $m_{e_1}(v) = 0 \forall v \in <e_1,Ae_1,A^2 e_1,\cdots>, m_A = m_{e_1}$

Comment: But...I still don't know how to prove Hamilton Cayley...without using Frobenius form. We didn't see it in the course...I think there should be another way

Comment: Pedro, you are using Hamilton-Cayley, and I'm supposed to prove this without using it, as this is the first part of an alternative proof of the theorem. Remember that tomorrow during the exam!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have checked that $P=x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ is the minimal degree monic polynomial such that $P[A](e_1)=0$, so you just need to show that $P[A](e_i)=0$ for every $i>1$ as well.

Now no doubt you noticed during your calculation that $e_i=A^{i-1}(e_1)$. Then $$P[A](e_i)=P[A](A^{i-1}(e_1)) =  A^{i-1}(P[A](e_1))=A^{i-1}(0)=0,
$$
because polynomials in $A$ commute with each other, and you are done.

In general, if some polynomial in $A$ kills a vector (here $v=e_1$), then it also kills its repeated images by$~A$, and their span. Stated differently, the kernel of the polynomial in $A$ is an $A$-stable subspace.